Problems after upgrading from 24.04 to 24.10 version
After a short period of operation, the image on the monitor consists of short vertical white stripes and the system goes to the initial password entry screen. This process is cyclical.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
